# Calendarios Datepicker Jquery no se muestran

Tags: jquery

Tengo el código de dos calendario **JQuery** en mi formulario pero no se muestran, a pesar de que he copiado el codigo de una pagina oficial de **JQuery**:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

  <link href="styles.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>
  
  

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="javascript/valida_sancion.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./javascript/cambio.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./javascript/refrescado.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./javascript/borrar.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./javascript/limite.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./javascript/mostrar.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./javascript/ocultar.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./javascript/nombre.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./javascript/ventana.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./javascript/validar.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($){
  $.datepicker.regional['es'] = {
    closeText: 'Cerrar',
    prevText: '&#x3c;Ant',
    nextText: 'Sig&#x3e;',
    currentText: 'Hoy',
    monthNames: ['Enero','Febrero','Marzo','Abril','Mayo','Junio',
    'Julio','Agosto','Septiembre','Octubre','Noviembre','Diciembre'],
    monthNamesShort: ['Ene','Feb','Mar','Abr','May','Jun',
    'Jul','Ago','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dic'],
    dayNames: ['Domingo','Lunes','Martes','Mi&eacute;rcoles','Jueves','Viernes','S&aacute;bado'],
    dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Lun','Mar','Mi&eacute;','Juv','Vie','S&aacute;b'],
    dayNamesMin: ['Do','Lu','Ma','Mi','Ju','Vi','S&aacute;'],
    weekHeader: 'Sm',
    dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd',
    firstDay: 1,
    isRTL: false,
    showMonthAfterYear: false,
    yearSuffix: ''};
  $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['es']);
});    
 
   $(document).ready(function() {
           $("#datepicker1").datepicker({ appendText: ' Haga click para introducir una fecha' });
           $("#datepicker2").datepicker({ appendText: ' Haga click para introducir una fecha' });
        });
</script>


  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {    
    $('#cedula1').blur(function(){
    
        $('#info1').html('<img src="loader.gif" alt="" />').fadeOut(1000);

        var cedula1 = $(this).val();        
        var dataString = 'cedula1='+cedula1;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "comprobar_disponibilidad1.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function(data) {
                $('#info1').fadeIn(1000).html(data);
            }
        });
    });              
});    
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $('#cedula2').blur(function(){
    
        $('#info2').html('<img src="loader.gif" alt="" />').fadeOut(1000);

        var cedula2 = $(this).val();        
        var dataString = 'cedula2='+cedula2;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "comprobar_disponibilidad2.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function(data) {
                $('#info2').fadeIn(1000).html(data);
            }
        });
    });              
});    
</script>

    <script>    
    $(document).ready(function(){

      //Modificamos option de nuestro 'SELECT'
      $("#articulo").change(function(){

          $.ajax({
            url:"cambiar-datos-select.php",
            type: "POST",
            data:"id_select="+$("#articulo").val(),

            success: function(opciones){
              $("#apartado").html(opciones);
            }
          });
      });


      //Formulario procesar4
      $(document).on('submit', '#frm-sancion', function() {

        //Obtenemos datos formulario
        var data = $(this).serialize();  

        $.ajax({            
          type : 'POST',
          url  : 'procesar4.php',
          data : data,
          success :  function(data) { 
            $(".result").html(data); 
          }
        });    

        return false;

      });

    }); //Fin documento
  </script>
</head>

<body onload="refrescado();valida()">

<?php
@session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["user_id"]) || $_SESSION["user_id"]==null){
  print "<script>alert(\"Acceso invalido!\");window.location='index.php';</script>";
}
?>
<?php include "php/navbar.php"; ?>
<?php
include "conexion.php";
?>

<form id="frm-sancion" method="POST" name="sancion" action ="procesar4.php">
<h1>Generar Sanción<br></h1>

   <div>
   <label>Ingrese cedula del sancionado:</label>
   <input type="text" id="cedula1" name="cedula1">
   <label id="info1">
   </div>
   


   <div>
   <label>Ingrese cedula del sancionador:</label>
   <input type="text" id="cedula2" name="cedula2">
   <label id="info2">
   </div>
   

 <div>
 <label>Ingrese tipo de sanción:</label>
 <select name="sancion">
<?php
global $cone;
  $registros = mysqli_query($cone, "select * from sanciones");
  while ($reg = mysqli_fetch_array($registros)) {
       echo "<option value=" . $reg['id_sancion']  . ">" . $reg['sancion']  . "<br/>" . "</option>";
  
  }
?>
      </select>
    </div>



  <div>
  <label>Ingrese articulo inflingido:</label>
  <select name="articulo" id="articulo">
      <option value="0">Seleccione un art+iculo:</option>
      <?php
    $registros = mysqli_query($cone, "SELECT * FROM articulos");
    $descripciones = '';
    while ($reg = mysqli_fetch_array($registros)) {
        echo "<option value=" . $reg['id_articulo'] . ">" . $reg['articulo'] . "</option>";
    }
  ?>
    </select>

  <div>
  <label>Ingrese aparte:</label>
  <select id="apartado" name="aprtado"> 
    <option value="0">Seleccione primero un articulo</option> 
  </select>      
</div>

<div class="result"><!-- Resultado AJAX procesar --></div>

  <div>
     <label>Ingrese Fecha inicial de la sanción:</label>
     <input type="text" name="fecha1" readonly id="datepicker1">
    </div>

<div>
     <label>Ingrese Fecha Final de la sanción:</label>
     <input type="text" name="fecha2" readonly id="datepicker2" >
</div>

<div>
     <label>Ingrese la observación:</label>
     <input type="text" name="observacion" name="observacion">
</div>


<div>
<label>Ingrese tipo de circuntancia:</label></br>
<input type="radio" name="tipo_sancion" id="ninguno" onclick="toggle(this);" value ="0" checked > Ninguno </br>
<input type="radio" name="tipo_sancion" id="comida fuerte" onchange="darNombre(this);" onclick="toggle(this);borrar();limite;" value="1"> Comida Fuerte <br/>
<input type="radio" name="tipo_sancion" id="comida sopa" onchange="darNombre(this);" onclick="toggle(this);borrar();limite;" value="2"> Comida Sopa <br/>
</div>   
    
<div id="uno">
Elija su comida fuerte

<?php
global $cone;
$registros= mysqli_query($cone, "SELECT * FROM comida_fuerte");
while($comida = mysqli_fetch_array($registros)){
echo "</br>"."<input type='checkbox'  onclick='validacionMaximo(this);' name='comida_fuerte[]'
value='".$comida['id_comida_fuerte']."'>".$comida['desc_comida_fuerte']."</br>";
}
?>
</div>

<div id="dos">
Elija su sopa

<?php
global $cone;
$registros2= mysqli_query($cone, "SELECT * FROM comida_sopa");
while($comida2 = mysqli_fetch_array($registros2)){
echo "</br>"."<input type='checkbox' name='comida_sopa[]'  onclick='validacionMaximo(this);' value='".$comida2["id_comida_sopa"]."'>".$comida2["desc_comida_sopa"]."</br>";
}
?>
</div>


<div>
<label>Elija las circunstancias:</label>
<select name="circunstancias">

<?php
global $cone;
  $registros = mysqli_query($cone, "select * from circunstancias");
  while ($reg = mysqli_fetch_array($registros)) {
       echo "<option value=" . $reg['id_circunstancia']  . ">" . $reg['desc_circunstancia']  . "<br/>" . "</option>";
  
  }
?>
      </select>
</div>

<div>
<label>Elija la documentación:</label>

<?php
global $cone;
$registros= mysqli_query($cone, "SELECT * FROM documentos");
while($comida = mysqli_fetch_array($registros)){
echo "</br>"."<input type='checkbox' name='documentos[]' value='".$comida['id_documento']."'>".$comida['desc_documento']."</br>";
}
?>
</div>

<button type="submit" id="registrar" value="registrar">Enviar</button>
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tienes muchas bibliotecas de Jquery, solo deja Jquery y Jquery UI para tales casos, uno de cada uno, y así mimo con el estilo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Edit

**A.**

Falta la librería ui de jquery: `https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js` inclúyela al principio y funcionará. Mira la prueba en [jsfidle](https://jsfiddle.net/acedano/mk8gppht/):

```
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

El ejemplo de jsfiddle usa las librerías siguientes:

```
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js
https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js
```

Aunque tienes una librería llamada: `http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js` tu código no funciona, porque la misma debe ser llamada con http**s**, he hecho la prueba en jsfiddle. Esa librería puedes borrarla y dejar la indicada más arriba en la respuesta, la versión 1.12.1 :) Aunque si quieres seguir con la 1.10.1 te funcionará si le pones una **s** después de http

**B.**

En cuanto a las librerías redundantes, borra las duplicadas, dejando las que tengan el número de versión mayor, pues estarán más actualizadas. También puede haber librerías que se llamen diferente y hagan lo mismo, pero eso es cuestión tuya investigarlo y decidir usar una u otra :)

Comment: no hace nada, incluso copie esto: 
https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/ y no muestra nada.

Comment: ¿Has probado que el php que llamas llega a `success`? Puedes comprobarlo poniendo algo como `console.log(data)` después de `success :  function(data) { `

Comment: ese succes muestra en el label si la cedula esta registrada o no, esto comprobando con la base de datos, todo el javascript funciona bien pero no muestra el calendario, incluso trate colocando como comentario todo el codigo yno funciona

Comment: A ver si me aclaro: ¿en qué parte del html quieres mostrar el calendario? supongo que en este div: `<div class="result">` y que para mostrarlo estás haciendo una llamada al archivo `procesar4.php` desde AJAX. ¿Es correcto?

Comment: Te faltaba una librería, mira la respuesta editada y un fragmento de tu código funcionando en jsfidle. :)

Comment: excelente :) ya funciona.

Comment: Me alegro de que haya funcionado  :)